Why ins't this SU(4) Matrix produced by the exponential map?
I was working with the SU(4) Lie group, which is compact and simply connected. This should imply that the exponential map is sujective on the group.
However i came across the matrix $$G=\begin{pmatrix}i & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & i & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & i & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & i\end{pmatrix},$$
which is special unitary, but does not seem to be the exponential of any algebra element, since $$log(G)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{i\pi}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & \frac{i\pi}{2} & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & \frac{i\pi}{2} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{i\pi}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$
is not traceless.
How could this be? Could someone help me see what I am missing here?
